# Asterisk AMI no longer allows connection

Tags: python, asterisk

I have been connecting my Python script to Asterisk AMI and things have been fine but suddenly it just stopped receiving connections I suppose. My manager.conf looks like this

```
[general]
enabled = yes
port = 5038
bindaddr = 0.0.0.0
displayconnects = yes

[myusername]
secret = mysecret
deny=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
permit=111.222.333.444/255.255.255.0
read = all
write = all
```

Suddenly it just stopped working. I tried to connect to the address 111.222.333.444 with the port 5038 on Telnet using Putty but the connection was refused. Please what might go wrong suddenly?

Comment: Debug is offtopic on SO.

Comment: I don't get you. What do you mean?

Comment: I did telnet and it shows that it is connected. So I tried to run "Asterisk Call Manager". I took a long time to give the error "Connection closed by foreign host"

Comment: There are no any ways solve your question by provided info. You have debug it. Debug is offtopic on this site. For debug i can recomend you use tcpdump utility or asterisk with debug more turned on.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
asterisk*CLI> manager show status
```

to verify for the interface.
Also you can do it from Linux, it's a standard TCP socket:

```
netstat -lna | grep 5038

netstat -lnap | grep asterisk
```

Answer (score -1):

Try these:

```
Action: Login
Username: username
Secret: password
```

Hit two enters then.

Try to paste it from clipboard instead of typing. It may time out otherwise.

I'm reading that you have tried PuTTY I guess from a remote machine and you got "connection refused". Butt using telnet on the local machine Works for you, so it must be a firewall problem (iptables?).

Comment: [root@developer~]# telnet 111.222.333.444 5038
Trying 111.222.333.444...
Connected to 111.222.333.444.
Escape character is '^]'.
ACTION: LOGIN USERNAME: myusername SECRET: mypassword. I get the error "Connection closed by foreign host"

Comment: Sorry, stackoverflow removed the new lines. It's three different lines and then two new lines required. It should say "Success, Authentication accepted". So it may be a timeout or an other error. Check the asterisk log file.